# MVC3 Razor For Multilanguage

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, multilingual

I have MVC3 with razor application here i want to  implement  multilingual functionality.

Plz suggest How i will do that .

Thanx in advanced

Sandeep Jain

Comment: -1 for not having the politeness to write "please" instead of "plz".

Answer (score 2):

You may take a look at the [following guide](http://adamyan.blogspot.com/2010/02/aspnet-mvc-2-localization-complete.html).

Comment: Thax Darin for reply , but i am using the MVC3 with razor , and i have issue with .cshtml file , here how i can chnage the text of the html pag according to the selected language like viewbag.title. . I used the syntext like viewbag.title="Resources.Resource.Title" , but getting the error. Plz suggest me how i can resolve that .

Answer (score 0):

This is another option, it's working great for me: http://subvert.ca/Blog/MVC3-multi-language